# Spring boot application runs locally but Heroku is throwing ClassNotFoundException on org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, heroku

I am trying to deploy a spring boot application to heroku. I have connected to my ClearDBSQL database fine and it runs great when I start the application in Eclipse, but when I deploy to heroku it is throwing a ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.

Pom file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cps.capstone</groupId>
    <artifactId>Capstone</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Capstone</name>
    <description>Capstone for Dev10</description>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>project.local</id>
            <name>project</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jfugue/jfugue -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfugue</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfugue</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>

                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.3</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

ProcFile:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=8080 -Dspring.profiles.active=default -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.cpb.capstone.Capstone.CapstoneApplication server
```

SpringApplication class in question:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CapstoneApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CapstoneApplication.class, args);
        
    }

}
```

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waphE.png)

I've been fighting this for a couple of days- the logging from Heroku is very short and sparse, and I've finally managed to get a stack trace of some kind of error. If there is a way to get more verbose logs to see what is actually happening, I'm all ears! Why is Heroku not finding SpringApplication? It seems like a pretty basic thing to have a disconnect about.

Answer (score 1):

when you build your application and have this in your `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Springs plugin will build a FAT jar file, that you run like a regular java application using the `-jar` flag.

So change your procfile to:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=8080 -Dspring.profiles.active=default -jar target/Capstone-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Reference:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-executable-jar

Edit:

the spring plugin needs to be in the build section of the `pom.xml` otherwise it wont get invoked during the building process.

```
<build>
    </plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am now getting "no main manifest attribute, in target/Capstone-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: that is because the plugin is not getting invoked so it is not building a fat jar that has a correct manifest file. Its because you have added your `pluginManagment` section. You can remove that entire section, and run on the defaults and just have the spring maven plugin in the build section, i have updated my answer.

Comment: So I'm understanding correctly- remove the whole <dependencies> tag in the pom? Sorry, I'm newer to programming and still trying to figure some things out

Comment: i corrected my comment, remove the entire `pluginManagement` section, you can run on the default maven plugin versions. And then only include the code i wrote above (the build section with the plugin). Here is a link to one of my poms look at the bottom. https://github.com/Tandolf/transform/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Thank you! I am learning a lot! I have the service up, but my pages aren't displaying. Another problem but an exciting step!

Comment: And how about gradle ? Note that it only broke when trying to upgrade from java 13 to 18, and upgrading gradle 4 to 6.5.